# Aborting thread sleep on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, signals, sleep

I'm a newbie linux developer, so I don't know exactly how to solve a problem.

In my main I spawn many worker threads, each one executes its task and sleeps for a few seconds.

In some circumstances I have to terminate. I need to avoid to wait for each sleep termination, so I want to send a signal to each thread to interrupt the sleep (nanosleep in my case) and terminate the threadproc loop.

I read a lot of documents about pthread_kill, but when I send, for example a SIGUSR1 to a thread, the process terminates in an abnormal way.

Could somebody point me to the solution?

Thank you very much!!!

> **Edit:** ***Solved***, the solution was `pthread_cond_timedwait` and `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: You might want to google "condition variables".

Comment: Are you talking about pthread_cond_timedwait? Regards.

Comment: I don't know the details of your code but it sounds like a job for condition variables: http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthread_cond.html

Comment: Why do the threads sleep? If they have work to do, they should be doing it. If they have no work to do, they should be waiting for work, not sleeping. Ideally, you would just use some normal mechanism to tell the threads there is no more work, the same way you tell them there is more work. Otherwise, look at pthread_cancel or condition variables. But most likely, the design is just bad.

Comment: Thank you Galik, I've read the link you suggested and and this maybe the solution...

Comment: I've just implemented the solution based upon the pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_timedwait and I confirm that if works!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your code but it sounds like a job for condition variables: [cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthread_cond.html](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/pthread_cond.html) – Galik

I've just implemented the solution based upon the `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_timedwait` and I confirm that if works!!! – Dare Devil

Answer (score 0):

In sending a signal, you're doing the right thing.
The only thing that is missing is catching that signal. You have to replace the signal action with your own one. In the signal handler you can set a variable and check for it after sleep returns.
Look into `sigaction`